# Can you run command line tools on Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-touch

Is there a way to run command line tools on Ubuntu Touch?

Could I run things like vim, gcc, ssh in a terminal app? Or is touch completely disjoint from the normal Linux world, and can it only run "apps" specifically written for the platform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can of course run all programs without graphical output via command line on Ubuntu Touch. It's only that right now there is no terminal available on the device itself.

That means that you can only invoke the command via adb or via ssh.

But the [terminal](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/CoreApps/Terminal) will be available soon IMHO.